# Derivative of a complex function $y=\operatorname{tg}2x^{\cot\frac x 2}$

Tags: derivatives

I have:
$y=(\operatorname{tg}2x)^{\operatorname{ctg}\frac x 2}$

So I solve:
\begin{align}
y' & =(\operatorname{tg}2x)^{\operatorname{ctg}\frac x 2}  \cdot \ln\operatorname{tg}2x \cdot (\operatorname{ctg}\frac x 2)' \\[10pt]
& =(\operatorname{tg}2x)^{\operatorname{ctg}\frac x 2}  \cdot \ln\operatorname{tg}2x \cdot -\frac 1 { \sin\frac x 2^2  } \cdot (\frac x 2) ' \\[10pt]
& = (\operatorname{tg}2x)^{\operatorname{ctg} \frac x 2} \cdot \ln\operatorname{tg}2x  \cdot (-\frac{ 1 }{ \sin^2\frac x 2}) \cdot \frac 1 2 = - \frac{ ({\operatorname{tg}2x})^{\operatorname{ctg}{\frac x 2} }  \cdot \ln \operatorname{tg}2x}{2\sin^2{\frac x 2} }
\end{align}

But, they told me that I was mistaken. Why so?

Comment: is $\text{ tg }$ supposed to mean $\tan$ (tangent) and ctg supposed to mean $\cot$ (cotangent)?  use `\tan`  and `\cot`

Comment: also is it $\tan(2x^{\cot()})$ or $(\tan(2x))^{\cot()}$?

Comment: ${(\tan(2x))}^{\cot()}$

Comment: Well, $\tan, \cot$ are used in some places (like the US) but $\mathrm{tg}, \mathrm{ctg}$ are used in other places.  We cannot say one is right and the other is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y = \tan^{\cot(\frac x2)}(2x)$

$\ln(y) = \cot(\frac x2)\ln(\tan{(2x)})$

Differentiating wrt x;

$$\frac{y'}{y} = -\dfrac{\operatorname{cosec}^2(\frac x2)}2\cdot\ln(\tan(2x))+\dfrac{1}{\tan(2x)}\cdot\sec^2(2x)\cdot2\cdot\cot(\frac x2)$$

$$y' = y\bigg[-\frac{\operatorname{cosec}^2(\frac x2)} 2 \cdot \ln(\tan(2x)) + 2\cot(2x)\cdot\cot(\frac x2)\bigg]$$

$$y'=\tan^{\cot(\frac x2)}(2x)\bigg[-\dfrac{\operatorname{cosec}^2(\frac x2)}2\cdot\ln(\tan(2x))+2\cot(2x)\cdot\cot(\frac x2)\bigg]$$

Your mistake was when you forgot to differentiate $\ln(\tan(2x))$

generally for functions of the type $y=f(x)^{g(x)}$ use $\ln(y)= g(x) \cdot \ln(f(x))$

Answer (score 1):

Generally you have
$$
\frac d {dx} u^v = u^v \log_e u \cdot \frac {dv}{dx} \quad + \quad vu^{v-1} \cdot \frac {du}{dx}.
$$
The first term is done just as if $u$ were constant, and the second as if $v$ were constant.